# Problem with classpath involving imports from a jar file

Tags: java, classpath

I was having the same problem as mentioned here: [exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-wrong-name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4626551/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-diserver-wrong-name)

I had no problems executing with eclipse but with terminal I got a NoClassDef. Rising one folder and executing `java <package-name>.<class-name>` worked perfectly.

My simple code is the following:

```
package temp;

import org.fusesource.jansi.Ansi;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("I'm going to blow on the next line!");
        System.out.println( Ansi.ansi().eraseScreen().render("@|bold,red Hello|@ @|green World|@") );

    }

}
```

I know this code runs, because I copied it from the [Jansi's author page](https://github.com/huynhjl/jansi). It's a library to print in color on a windows' terminal. **What do I need to do to run this class?** Help is much appreciated.

---

[UDPATE: SOLUTION]

I was advised to create a jar of the application I was trying to test and then run that jar. So I created the jar "jprinter" containing all my files (not the external jar I was using) and the test class with the main. After that I could execute in any folder

```
java -cp ".\lib\jprinter-1.15.jar;.\lib\*" print.test.Test
```

where `lib` is the folder with my and other jars used; `print.test` is the package of the class `Test` which contains the main method.

---

[outdated:]
I tried executing by running `java .:..\lib\jansi-1.4.jar temp.Test` which gave me the following ouput:

```
I'm going to blow on the next line!
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/fusesource/jansi/Ansi
        at temp.Test.main(Test.java:13)
```

And I also tried executing by running `java ".:..\lib\jansi-1.4.jar" temp.Test` or `java ".;..\lib\jansi-1.4.jar" temp.Test` which gave me the following ouput:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: \lib\jansi-1.4\jar
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: .:..\lib\jansi-1.4.jar
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[UDPATE: SOLUTION]

I was advised to create a jar of the application I was trying to test and then run that jar. So I created the jar "jprinter" containing all my files (not the external jar I was using) and the test class with the main. After that I could execute in any folder

```
java -cp ".\lib\jprinter-1.15.jar;.\lib\*" print.test.Test
```

where `lib` is the folder with my and other jars used; `print.test` is the package of the class `Test` which contains the main method.

Answer (score 4):

You should add this library to your classpath.  Try running it like this:

```
java -cp .:<path_to_your_jansi_jar> temp.Test
```

Note that the delimiter is platform dependent.  On a Unix system ":" should be used, on a Windows system it will be ";":

```
java -cp .;<path_to_your_jansi_jar> temp.Test
```

In your particular case it will probably be like this:

```
java -cp .;..\lib\jansi-1.4.jar temp.Test
```

Comment: Yes you can do that.  Note that the <> should not be used, it was just to highlight that you should replace it with the path to your actual jar file.  I suppose it would be something like this in your case: `java -cp ../lib/jansi.jar temp.Test`

Comment: If you have two jars, one in lib and one in bin, calling {{java -cp ..\lib\jansi.jar -jar yourjar.jar}} from bin should work. Scooped by wjans, though. :)

Comment: @wjans: yes, I know about the <> :P
@Urs: Thx for the tip of two jars! I forgot the `..`

Comment: @jwans: I tried your solution but got another error 
`<...\SandBox\bin> java -cp ..\lib\jansi-1.4.jar temp.Test         
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: temp/Test
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: temp.Test
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) `

Comment: Oh, the current folder is not on your classpath anymore.  Try adding the current folder "." to your classpath as well.  Try it like this: `java -cp .;..\lib\jansi-1.4.jar temp.Test`.  I assume you're running on a windows system, if not use ":" instead of ";" as a delimiter.

Comment: I'm on windows. I tried the `;` and it didn't work whereas `:` did work. But the error still remains. I uploaded the eclipse project to this [link](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1862596/SandBox.zip)

Comment: What do you mean by "I tried the `;` and it didn't work"?  It should work fine.  Maybe you can put the classpath between quotes to be on the safe side.  `java -cp ".;..\lib\jansi-1.4.jar" temp.Test`

Comment: The quotes didn't work, I got another error, please check my edit at the original question.

Comment: In your edit you don't have -cp anymore.  If you specify it like this it should work:  `java -cp ".;..\lib\jansi-1.4.jar" temp.Test`.  Tried it with and without quotes, forward/backward slashes, ... it all works.

Answer (score 1):

You must specify -classpath where "org.fusesource.jansi.Ansi" is found. See for detail [classpath](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/tooldocs/win32/classpath.html)

or better [classpath](http://www.roseindia.net/java/java-classpath.shtml)